# $A-B$ and $B-A$ positive semidefinite $\implies$ $A=B$

Tags: matrices

I am trying to show that $A-B$ and $B-A$ positive semidefinite $\implies A=B$, but I'm having some trouble.

$A-B$ PSD iff $x'(A-B)x \geq 0 \forall x$, and $B-A$ PSD iff $x'(B-A)x \geq 0 \forall x$.

Both of these are true iff $$x'Ax=x'Bx \forall x,$$

which holds iff $$x'(A-B)x=0, \forall x,$$

$$\iff x \perp (A-B)x, \forall x$$

But this holds if, for instance, (A-B) is a 90-degree rotation. It doesn't seem to require $A-B=0$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of a positive semi-definite matrix requires the matrix to be symmetric (or Hermitian in the complex case). This will rule out the possibility that $A-B$ is a rotation matrix.

As for proving this statement, suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ symmetric matrices. Let $e_k$ be the $k$-th standard basis vector.

Since $x'(A-B)x = 0$ for all $x$ (as you have already deduced), we have that $e_k'(A-B)e_k = 0$, i.e. $(A-B)_{k,k} = 0$ for all $k$. Hence, the diagonal of $A-B$ is zero.

For sake of contradiction, suppose $(A-B)_{i,j} = \alpha \neq 0$ for some $i,j$ such that $i \neq j$. Since $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, $A-B$ is symmetric. So, $(A-B)_{j,i} = \alpha$ as well.

Now, what can you say about $(e_i+e_j)'(A-B)(e_i+e_j)$? Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Cool.  $(e_i+e_j)′(A−B)(e_i+e_j) = (A-B)_{ij} + (A-B)_{ji}=0$ and for symmetric $(A-B), (A-B)_{ij} + (A-B)_{ji}=0 \iff (A-B)_{ij} =0$. Thus $x'(A-B)x=0 \implies (A-B)_{ij}=0 \forall i,j$ if $A,B$ symmetric. Right?

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is using the spectral decomposition for $A - B$ (I am assuming it is symmetric), which gives
$$A - B = Odiag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)O^T,$$
where $O$ is orthogonal matrix and $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n \geq 0$ are eigenvalues of $A - B$ (since it is positive-semidefinite by condition). Hence
$$B - A = Odiag(-\lambda_1, \ldots, -\lambda_n)O^T.$$
That is, $B - A$ is orthogonal similar to a diagonal matrix $diag(-\lambda_1, \ldots, -\lambda_n)$, hence $-\lambda_1, \ldots, -\lambda_n$ are also eigenvalues of $B - A$. By assumption, $B - A$ is positive-semidefinite, therefore,
$$-\lambda_i \geq 0, i = 1, \ldots, n.$$

In this way, we can see that $\lambda_1 = \cdots = \lambda_n = 0$. Thus $A - B = 0$, or, $A = B$.